# How to create event handler class with listener and register in java?

Tags: java

I want to create connection between File and FileView with event logic.

I created new class eventHandler.

I want the the file will fire event when he finish to create and then I want that the FileView will be called becuase the FileView was register in the eventHandler.

I know how to do it in javascript but not in java

The idea is to do ViewPart->(listens to)EventHandler->(listens to)File
Do you know how I can implement this logic in java ?

```
 class File {
   private String path;
   private String name;
   public File(){
      path = calcPath();
      name = calcName()
      finish() -> fire the event to eventHandler
    }
   public finish() {
        // fire event to eventHandler
   }
..............
  }


  class FileView extends ViewPart {
         // Should register to listen to event in the eventHandler
        public functionShouldListenToEvent() {
               // need to register to event of eventHandler
           }
       public functionThatShouldTrigger(){
                //updateMyview
       }
   }


   class eventHandler{
            //Should keep the event that we register and also the listener
            //Should somehow get the event and check who is listen and the fire the event to the listeners 
    }
```

Comment: See [Writing Javabeans components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting your question right, you want something like this:

```
class File {
    private FileEventListener listener; // <- create getter/setter for this

    public finish() {
        listener.onFileFinished();
    }
}


class FileView extends ViewPart implements EventProxyListener {
    private EventProxy proxy = new EventProxy();

    // This is where you register this FileView as a listener to events from the proxy instance
    public FileView() {
        proxy.setListener(this); // <- This is ok because FileView implements EventProxyListener
    }

    // Implements onFinished, described in the EventProxyListener interface
    public void onProxyFinished() {
        // EventProxy has reported that it is done
    }
}

// This is the MiM-class that will clobber your code. I urge you to reconsider this design
class EventProxy implements FileEventListener {
    private EventProxyListener listener; // <- Create getter/setter for this
    private File file = new File();

    public EventProxy {
        file.setListener(this);
    }

    public void onFileFinished() {
        listener.onProxyFinished();
    }
}

interface EventProxyListener {
    public void onProxyFinished();
}

interface FileEventListener {
    public void onFileFinished();
}
```

Of course, there should be lots more error handling and stuff in there, but you get the gist...

Please tell me if I got your question wrong.

Peace!

Comment: not 100% , I don't want the FileView  will know on File EventListener  should do all the logic meaning to get the event from the File. and should get that FileView is listen to the changes.EventListener should check who is listen to the changes and the fire the event.

Comment: EventListener  should be class that will do all the logic and not interface

Comment: If you want your FileView to know when an event has been triggered it will have to have some sort of callback channel. Interfaces are usually the way to do that. Of course, you could have a handler in the middle, making an information flow like this ViewPart->(listens to)EventHandler->(listens to)File. But that is probably just going to make your code more complicated than necessary.
Could you paste some of the logic you intended to have in the EventHandler?

Comment: this is what I want iewPart->(listens to)EventHandler->(listens to)File and of course File trigger the event and I didn't know how to do it.I will update my code

Comment: I don't have any logic in class EventHandler it just should get the event keep the listener and trigger the event to the listener

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to reflect the changes. As you can see, it will now involve two types of listeners (the interfaces) and a MiM-class (the proxy) that will handle the communication between the File class and the FileView class. 
This becomes quite messy, and it's not a design I would recommend. 
Peace.